# Incompatible magic value 1010792557 when trying to run applet embedded in Facelets

Tags: java, jsf, applet, glassfish, facelets

I get this error when I access the Facelets page where the applet is embedded, through Glassfish server. 
Though when I open it simply from my computer it works fine, so the applet is ok.
Is it possible to run applets on Glassfish (3.1, JSF 2.0)?

Here's how I try:

```html
<applet code="test.TestApplet" archive="TestApplet.jar"/>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution:

If I place the applet's jar file into the resources folder of my web application, and I set the archive file's path to it as the following

```
<applet code="test.TestApplet" archive="../resources/TestApplet.jar"/>
```

it works fine.

Comment: How exactly is this different from my answer? I explained how this problem is caused and boiled down that your `archive` URL is plain wrong.

Answer (score 7):

That's a typical message of a [`ClassFormatError`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassFormatError.html). The magic value of a valid Java class is `0xCAFEBABE`, which is the first 4 bytes. But you're getting `0x3C3F786D` which stands for the ASCII characters `<?xm`.

So, the request to `TestApplet.jar` has apparently *actually* returned a XML document. You should be able to see it yourself when you change the current request URI in browser address bar to point to `TestApplet.jar` file (i.e. change `/page.jsf` or `/page.xhtml` in end of URL to `/TestApplet.jar`). Then you'll see what the browser *actually* retrieved when it tried to download the applet. Perhaps it's a simple HTTP 404 error document served by Facelets.

To fix it, just make sure that the URL in the `archive` attribute is correct. It's relative to the current request URL as you see in browser address bar.