# Incompatible magic value 1010792557 for 1 client only

Tags: java, applet

I have one client getting this error whilst the applet is working properly for a number of other users.

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 1010792557 in class file %className%
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.AppletViewer.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.SecurityException: class "%className%"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.AppletViewer.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I believe that the magic value represents the start of an xml tag (based on this [Incompatible magic value 1010792557 when trying to run applet embedded in Facelets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030528/incompatible-magic-value-1010792557-when-trying-to-run-applet-embedded-in-facele/8031138#8031138)).  The security error occurs after the magic value error and I suspect its a byproduct of the first problem.

What I can't fathom is why this is happening to one client only.

All clients are using JRE version 1.6.0_24-b07 and IE 8.0.6001.18702.

On the clients machine I have tried clearing the cache, deleting temporary internet files, and deleting temporary internet files via the java control panel.  I have also tried deleting the certificate from the javacpl 'trusted certificates' list and even turning off verification from javacpl>Advanced>Security>Mixed Code.

I'm out of ideas and would love to hear any suggestions on what the problem/solution might be.

Oh, the applet is hosted in a java wicket project running on tomcat 7.0.19 via apache 2.2 (on windows server 2008).

Comment: It would help to install a HTTP traffic tracker like Fiddler2 to see what the client actually retrieved when the applet is been downloaded. It would also help to try another browser than IE to exclude it from being the culprit.

Comment: No other browsers as its a corporate app (intranet).  I'm a bit limited in what I can do with other tools (don't have full admin rights to host) but looking at access logs I can see a http 302 was returned when the request to load the applet was made, is this normal?

Comment: That's a redirect. Can you share the request/response headers? The 302 should have a `Location` header pointing to the new URL. You should see a new request on that URL in the access logs directly hereafter (only if the URL points to a resource at the same server, of course). It can happen that the webapp's code is conditionally performing a redirect based on the information provided in the request. Perhaps the enduser is unauthenticated? Perhaps some cookie is missing? Perhaps the user agent is wrong? Etc. Are you the developer or the serveradmin of the webapp?

Comment: Hmm, interestingly, the 302 is directly followed by a req for the web application's login page (which would start with '<?xm').  Successful requests to load the applet have 200 responses rather than 302's.  I'd be tempted to blame the internals of the web application at this point, except that the same user can use other client PCs and open the applet without issue.

Comment: Then it is just an authentication issue, as I already guessed. Surely you may blame the webapp developer about this if it isn't the server or proxy itself which did the redirect :) Perhaps he can tell how exactly the authentication is been performed so that all required parts can be individually verified. Perhaps it's after all cookie based and the enduser has just to enable cookies? Perhaps the datetime at the client side is wrong (too far in future or past) and hence the cookie was never valid? Etcetera.

Comment: Thanks BalusC.  I'll chase it up and report back here if fixed/or not.

Comment: I have managed to get the applet working by changing the way it is initialised.  Previously, the applet was loaded and initialized via ajax, by changing this to a more traditional open the applet in a new page approach it works.  Maybe there is a problem with IE security settings + ajax + applets on the problem client?  I'm not sure.