# Java applet not running from other locations

Tags: java, applet

I've taken the bin contents from my eclipse folder and pasted them along with an html in a folder accessible through apache.

Clicking the html brings up a java warning and cannot run, lowering the security to medium, allows the application to run without problems locally.

But when opening from other locations firefox and chrome give security warnings and do not display the app, even with java control panel set to medium also IE displays the following message

**incompatible magic value 218786157 in class**

I would like to know what could be causing the problem I'm using apache server with the guide from lifehacker to setting up your home web server.

Also if there's a way for the applet to run without modifying security settings.

PS  I've tested another programmers simple text single class applet and it loads from various locations and all three browsers without problem.   My application accesses png and wav files so I'm thinking there might be an issue with accessing files.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referencing the content (`.wav` file etc.) with relative or absolute path? Having absolute path may generate problems, when it accesses files that are not in the shared path, but elsewhere on the disc.

Make sure you use a path like `../resources/my.wav` that is relative to the applet location. Then in a folder that is one step up from that of applet and has name `resources`  should have that content in my case.

Would you have this kind of situation?

---

**Sources:**

[1] [Incompatible magic value 1010792557 when trying to run applet embedded in Facelets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030528/incompatible-magic-value-1010792557-when-trying-to-run-applet-embedded-in-facele)

Comment: Path is relative.  Figured out the problem was that the applet was in the server's root folder rather than a subfolder, putting it in a subfolder fixed the issue.   Now it works, but it seems only within my LAN connected computers.  Seems something additional is needed for it to work from locations outside lan.